# How to separate the php code from html and the code will still work as it is working! And print the $selection error variable above the selection menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to print the $selection_error variable on top of the selection menu but it is not working there but if I print the $selection_error variable below the table it is working. Is there any way to separate the php code from html by placing it on top of all the html code so that I could print the $selection_error variable on top of the selection menu?

I'm trying to add this code below the h3 tag above the form..

```
<?php if (isset($selection_error))  
        print_r("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
              $selection_error <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button> </div>");
?>
```

not exactly below the table as it is shown in the code!

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <?php include("includes/navbar.php"); ?>
  <!--./Navigation  -->
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Page Heading -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h3 class="page-header">
             <div class="text-center" style="letter-spacing: 1.5px;">
                View Student Information
             </div>
          </h3>        
          <div class="formstyle">
            <form class="form-inline st" action="" method="POST">
              <label for="sel11" class="form-control-label ab">Select Semester</label>

<?php
$query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM semester ORDER BY sem_id ASC");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
  
                <select class="form-control" id="sel11" name="sel11">
                  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
<?php 
if($rowCount > 0){
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
      echo '<option value="'.$row['sem_id'].'">'.$row['sem_name'].'</option>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<option value="">Semester not available</option>';
}
?>
                </select>                  
              <label for="sel12" class="form-control-label ab">Start Session</label>

<?php
$query = $connection->query("SELECT DISTINCT(session_start) FROM student ORDER BY session_start ASC");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
  
                <select class="form-control" id="sel12" name="sel12">
                  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
<?php 
if($rowCount > 0){
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
      echo '<option value="'.$row['session_start'].'">'.$row['session_start'].'</option>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<option value="">Semester not available</option>';
}
?>              
                </select>                  
              <label for="sel13" class="form-control-label ab">End Session</label>

<?php
$query = $connection->query("SELECT DISTINCT(session_end) FROM student ORDER BY session_end ASC");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
  
                <select class="form-control" id="sel13" name="sel13">
                  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
<?php 
if($rowCount > 0){
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
      echo '<option value="'.$row['session_end'].'">'.$row['session_end'].'</option>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<option value="">Semester not available</option>';
}
?>
                </select>
                <div class="ab inline">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button> 
                </div>
            </form>               
          </div>          
          <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction2()" placeholder="Search for roll no or names..">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Roll No</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Email</th>
                  <th scope="col">Start Session</th>
                  <th scope="col">End Session</th>
                  <th scope="col">Semester</th>
                  <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

<?php 
$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if(isset($_POST['sel11']) && isset($_POST['sel12']) && isset($_POST['sel13'])){

    $sel11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['sel11']);
    $sel12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['sel12']);
    $sel13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['sel13']);


    $query = "SELECT * FROM student, semester WHERE student.session_start = '{$sel12}' AND student.session_end = '{$sel13}' AND student.sem_id = semester.sem_id AND student.sem_id = '{$sel11}' ORDER BY student.s_rollno ASC";
    $select_student_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $rowCount = $select_student_query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0){
      $i = 0;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_student_query)) {
        $s_id = $row['s_id'];
        $s_rollno = $row['s_rollno'];
        $s_email = $row['s_email'];
        $s_name = $row['s_name'];
        $session_start = $row['session_start'];
        $session_end = $row['session_end'];
        $sem_name =  $row['sem_name'];

        $i = $i + 1;

        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<th scope='row'>$i</th>";
          echo "<td>$s_rollno</td>";
          echo "<td>$s_name</td>";
          echo "<td>$s_email</td>";
          echo "<td>$session_start</td>";
          echo "<td>$session_end</td>";
          echo "<td>$sem_name</td>";
          echo "<td>
              <div class='btn-group'>
                <a href='updateStudent.php?update={$s_id}' class='btn btn-warning' role='button'>Edit</a>
                <a href='viewStudentInfo.php?delete={$s_id}' class='btn btn-danger' role='button'>Delete</a>
              </div>
          </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='text-center' colspan='8'>";
            echo "<h3 class='text-danger'>No Data Found!</h3>";
        echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";

    }
  }
  else {
    $error = true;
    $selection_error = "Select at least one option from each dropdown list!";    
  }
}
 ?> 
              </tbody>
            </table>   

<?php if (isset($selection_error))  
        print_r("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
              $selection_error <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button> </div>");
?> 

<?php 

if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
  $s_id = $_GET['delete'];

  $query = "DELETE FROM student WHERE s_id = '{$s_id}'";
  $delete_student_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

   header("Location: viewStudentInfo.php");

}

 ?>              
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
  <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code. You're using both styles here inconsistently.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These typically implement the Model-View-Controller pattern which provides better separation from code and HTML.